# Angular 2 - window with pin number after clicking button

Tags: angular, popupwindow

I would like to create popup window with pin number after clicking button. After entering pin json data will be send to the database about information if pin was entered properly.

Here is some of my code :

**lock-status.component.html**

```
<button type="button" (click)="addLog($event)" class="btn btn-success btn-open">OPEN DOORS <i class="fa fa-key fa-3x"></i></button>
```

**lock-status.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {LogService} from '../../services/log.service';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {Log} from '../../Log';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'lock-status',
    templateUrl: 'lock-status.component.html'
})
export class LockStatusComponent implements OnInit {
    logs: Log[];

    constructor(private _logService:LogService) { }

    ngOnInit(){
    this.logs = [];
    this._logService.getLogs()
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(logs => this.logs = logs);
    }

    addLog($event){
        if($event.which === 1){
            var result;
            var d=new Date();
            var newLog={
                datka: String(d),
                isCompleted: true
            };

            result=this._logService.saveLog(newLog);
            result.subscribe(x =>{this.logs.push(newLog)})
        }
    }

 }
```

Have u got any ideas how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at modal popup windows in this library ng2-bs3-modal.  You pop the window on your button click, present the pin or request the pin, and then on the ok/confirm button, you perform your logic, then navigate to where you need to be.